# Find number of ways to divide a set into 2 parts

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, multisets

In how many ways can we divide a set into 2 parts having an element in equal number in both of resulting subsets.

For example,
`multiset = {1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5}` and element being '5', one set of two subset can be `{5, 1, 2, 3, 5}`, `{5, 5}`

I tried taking combinations of the number of occurrence of the element taking half of them at a time but I am not sure is it is correct.

Comment: When you say "an element", do you mean a specified element, or exactly one element, or at least one element?

Comment: Sets can't have multiples of the same element. In this case $\{1,2,3,5,5,5,5\} = \{1,2,3,5\}$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Presumably this should be a multiset.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I should update it to multiset, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: You didn't answer Robert Israel's comment. If you don't clarify it my answer might be meaningless to you.

Comment: If you mean exactly one kind of element may repeat in the your multi-set, then the answer is symply: $$\frac{\left|P(S\setminus R)\right|}{2},$$ where $P(S)$ means the power (multi-)set of $S$, and $R$ is the (multi-)set contains all repeated elements.

Comment: @RobertIsrael by "an element" I meant a specified element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cardinality of your specified element in your multiset is odd, there are no ways.  If even, each part must get half of these.  For each other element, if it has cardinality $m$, there are $m+1$ possibilities ($0, 1, \ldots, m$ of them in the first set, and the rest in the second).
So the answer, if the cardinality of the specified element is even, is the product of $m_i+1$ where $m_i$ is the cardinality of the $i$'th unspecified element of the multiset.